# why does the code print both answers even though they have different conditions

Tags: python

I'm writing a code to check if the key given exists in the dictionary or not, the code goes like this:

```
x=str()
def check_key(d,x):
    for i in d:
        if i==x:
            print("exists")
        else:
            print("not exist")
check_key({'etisalat':'011','vodafone':'010'},"etisalat")
```

the problem is, if it exists, the code prints exists and not exist, and if it doesn't exist it prints not exist twice, what do I need to edit?

tried changing indentation of the print statements, tried putting them into variables and returning the value but it doesn't return

```
x=str()
def check_key(d,x):
    for i in d:
        if i==x:
            print("exists")
        else:
            print("not exist")
check_key({'etisalat':'011','vodafone':'010'},"etisalat")
```

the output is (exists,not exist) if it exists, and (not exist,not exist) if it doesn't exist, it's supposed to print one output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dict has two keys, you are looping and testing twice and thus getting two prints. Try:

```
def check_key(d,x):
    for i in d:
        if i==x:
            print("exists")
            return
    print("not exist")

check_key({'etisalat':'011','vodafone':'010'},"etisalat")
```

You can also test directly instead of looping:

```
def check_key(d,x):
    if x in d:
        print("exists")
    else:
        print("not exist")

check_key({'etisalat':'011','vodafone':'010'},"etisalat")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `for i in d` you are looping over every item in the dictionary. Thus you will do something for both keys in the dictionary.

You do not need to write this function, it already exists. It's the `in` method of a dictionary.

```
d = {'etisalat':'011','vodafone':'010'}
print('etisalat' in d)
>>> True
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If something is helpful you should upvote it rather than saying thanks.